# Limit of a Sum as $n \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, summation

I'm trying to evaluate this problem. The answer is $e^2 - e$, but I can't seem to get to that answer.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{i/n} \right )$$

Comment: The sum of *what*?

Comment: sorry, fixed it.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{i/n}$ is the sum of a geometric progression, it can be calculated explicitly.

Comment: I got that the limit is $e-1$. Is this what you are getting as well? The sum has $n$ terms that are at most $e^{n/n} = e$, so the limit can't have a value larger than $e$.

Comment: That's also what I get: $e-1$.

Comment: what if it was e/n instead of 1/n?

Comment: Then of course it would be $e^2-e$.  But that outside $e$ doesn't play much of an interesting role, then.

Answer (score 3):

Treat it as a Riemann sum 
$$
\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n f\Bigl(\frac in\Bigr)=\sum_{i=1}^n f(i\Delta t)\Delta t 
$$
and conclude that it converges towards the integral.

Answer (score 3):

As currently written, the limit appears to be $e-1$:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n e^{k/n}\right)
    & = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{1/n}-e^{1+1/n}}{n\left(1-e^{1/n}\right)} \\
    & = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(1+1/n)(1-e)}{n[1-(1+1/n)]} \\
    & = \frac{1-e}{-1} = e-1
\end{align}

Comment: what if it was e/n instead of 1/n?

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{i/n} \right )=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\frac{(e-1) e^{1/n}}{e^{1/n}-1}=
(e-1)\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{ n^{-1}e^{1/n}}{e^{1/n}-1}
=(e-1)\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{ x^{-1}e^{1/x}}{e^{1/x}-1}
=(e-1)\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{ x^{-1}e^{1/x}}{e^{1/x}-1}
=(e-1)\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^3}-\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^2} }{-\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^2}}=
(e-1)\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac1x) = e-1
$$

After $n$ turns to $x$ L'Hospital is used.